# Java 8 : map.merge time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, java-8

I am trying to find the complexity of below code, because of `for` loop it will be O(n * `complexity_of_map.merge`)

```
public int solution(int K, int[] A) {    
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i =0; i < A.length; i++){
        map.merge(K - A[i], 1, Integer::sum);
    }   
    return Arrays.stream(A).map(element -> map.getOrDefault(element,0)).sum();
}
```

Can someone help me to understand the time complexity of above code and `map.merge()`
in Java 8.

Comment: You want to write a [MCVE] for this.

Comment: @pvg What extra information you need to answer this question?

Comment: Just some style notes. Since Java 5, you can use for-each: `for(int a: A) map.merge(K - a, 1, Integer::sum);` and since Java 7, you don’t need to repeat the type parameters at instantiations: `Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As quoted from Javadoc of JDK 8:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-

> The default implementation is equivalent to performing the following
>   steps for this map, then returning the current value or null if
>   absent:
>
> ```
> V oldValue = map.get(key);
> V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
>           remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
> if (newValue == null)
>     map.remove(key);
> else
>     map.put(key, newValue);
> ```

All `put`, `remove` and `get` are `O(1)` for `HashMap`.  `remappingFunction` you are using is `Integer::sum` which has nothing to do with `n`. So the for loop in your solution is simply `O(n)`.

For the stream operation, stream + map + sum should be roughly equivalent to a simple for loop, which makes it `O(n)`.  The lambda you passed to `map()` is calling `map.getOrDefault`, which is also `O(1)` for `HashMap`.  So that's also `O(n)` overall.

So your solution is simply `O(n)`.

Comment: I was thinking the same... Good answer

Comment: `Map.getOrDefault` is `O(1)`. By the way, if you are looking at `HashMap` specifically, the `default` implementation becomes irrelevant, as `HashMap` overrides the `merge` method. But, of course, it does not make the operation worse, so it’s still `O(1)`.

Comment: Oops typo on this :)